# Problem with USB installation (xbmcbuntu)

Tags: installation, usb, xbmc

This question is about XBMCbuntu, which is basically ubuntu - So I hope it is okay to ask:
Iv'e been trying for the last many hours to install xbmcbuntu. I've downloaded to ISOs 12.2 and 12 - Both in Intel&Nvidia editions (Intel proc. & nvidia gfx). Ive tried formatting my USBpen to FAT, FAT32, NTFS. Used Universal USB Tool, UNetbootin and Lili. None of which have worked.

First of all, my windows 7 is install via USB - the same USB key, so I know what i'm doing.
When i first started trying to install via USB I got a Syslinux error, which caused me to try the different USB tools. None of which worked. Then I tried formatting the drive to different settings, which now has resulted in to different outcomes.

Either I get stuck when I try to boot from the USB - Nothing happens(No text or anything) and then it freezes and needs a hard reboot. Or it simply ignores the USBstick and starts booting windows as normal.

Now - I'm very confused - Can ANYONE tell my how to install this?

Also - have tried LiLi from windows - thought I'd might be able to install it from windows. But no drives show up when I get to it in the installer.

Hopefully some of you know what to do...

Comment: Why not install Ubuntu the XBMC over it?

Comment: Will that be as lightweight? And can I make it boot straight into Xbmc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if it's basically an Ubuntu you could follow this instructions

[Ubuntu LiveUSB installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Answer (score 0):

When i first tried instaling winXP in mi laptop i had to inject the sata drive drivers in the instalation image. So, question 1, have you installed any other distro to that same machine? If not, try and do that with a more mainstream and complete distro and see if it works. If you did and it worked, mi guess is that the problem is with your machine and that distro.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use the MinimalCD and install only the packages you want. Download the MinimalCD from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and select the packages you would want for your system. This install Ubuntu in a baremetal-like, which only have the minimum packages installed.